# cryptopp on centos4.8 segmentation fault when link with pthread

Tags: c++, linux, centos, crypto++

I have a program compiled and running on centos4.8.  I have downloaded and compiled cryptopp 5.6.2 into a static library.  When running a test program I get a segmentation fault on call to

```
CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
e.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), ctr ); // segmentation fault here
```

I can recreate this in a small program.  If I link with libpthread.a I get the fault, if I do not link with it, the program runs as expected.

My application depends on linking with pthread, so I am hoping to find a way to compile cryptopp that is compatible.
Thank you

Comment: assuming you are using g++ do you link like `g++ <code> -o <output> -pthread` or do you use `-lpthread`? You should use `-pthread` without the 'l'.

Comment: this is my compile batch

    g++ -g -o testcrypto \
    testmod.c \
    -lstdc++ -lcryptopp -static -pthread

Comment: More information...when making the cryptopp library I run make static test.  If I run the aes ctr test "cryptest.exe ae 00000000000000000000000000000000 000000000000000000000000000000000 myfile.txt myfile.encrypted" there is no segmentation fault

Comment: additional information...if I remove -static then the test program compiles and runs a-ok.  Will investigate the need for this in our full application

Comment: more information...If I force #define CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION everything seems ok

Answer (score 1):

So it seems...

On CentOS 4.8 with gcc 3.4.6 cryptopp needs #define CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION when linking statically.  Hope this saves someone some time!