# C++ Segmentation Fault CryptoPP Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-18.04, crypto++

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to run a CryptoPP function.

Info, and GDB output are below:

1. generate_aes_key() function is called in the main(..) method. The last line "Done gen keys" prints out. Then it seg faults in the main(..) on return

Then I get the output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
void generate_aes_key() {
    try {
        AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
        SecByteBlock key = SecByteBlock(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        SecByteBlock iv = SecByteBlock(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
        prng.GenerateBlock(key.data(), key.size());
        prng.GenerateBlock(iv.data(), iv.size());
        std::cout << "Done gen keys" << endl;
        
    }

    catch (CryptoPP::Exception e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**GDB says:**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040c414 in CryptoPP::member_ptr<CryptoPP::BlockCipher>::~member_ptr
    (this=0x7fffffffdd58, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at ../external-libs/include/cryptopp/smartptr.h:69
69 template <class T> member_ptr<T>::~member_ptr() {delete m_p;}
```

**INFO ABOUT ENVIRONMENT:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**COMPILER COMMANDS:**

```
g++ -g -c -static -pthread -I../ -I/data/my_project/external-libs/include/cryptopp/ ../src/security/encryption/lib_encrypt.cpp

g++ -g ../lbin/*.o -static -pthread -o server -L/data/my_project/external-libs/lib/ -lz -l:libcryptopp.a
```

Based on this thread:

[cryptopp on centos4.8 segmentation fault when link with pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527947/cryptopp-on-centos4-8-segmentation-fault-when-link-with-pthread)

I also added to the header file the #define

```
#ifndef LIB_ENCRYPT_HPP
#define LIB_ENCRYPT_HPP

#define CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION
```

Comment: Why don't you pass it to g++ `-DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was some corruption with the .a library or the header files maybe.

I went back to cryptopp directory, **make clean**, **make**. ran the ./cryptest.exe t  for the basic DES check.

Copied the folder into my headers and copied the .a file.

Cleaned out all my old object files, rebuilt the source and it started working.